# Cookies randomly come and go, they are not persistent from one tab to the next or across browser restarts

Tags: cookies

While developing with http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 cookies are not present on all browser tabs.  Inspecting in dev tools shows no cookies when a new tab is opened but after going to a new route in the newly opened tab the cookies do re-appear magically...

I would expect for cookies to remain even after the browser itself is closed...and especially when simply a new tab to the same location is opened...

Cookies in chrome display random behavior, sometimes they are there and sometimes they are not.

Answer (score 0):

...This problem has plagued me for about a week now...It is important to understand that at least in chrome the cookies set for http://localhost are separate and different from those stored for http://127.0.0.1  So if you start by typing localhost into the browser bar and then the rest of your app redirects to 127.0.0.1 you will essentially be on what chrome thinks are two separate websites even though they are obviously enough to yourself the same site, same server.

Be aware of this distinction and try to use one or the other through and through while developing...I prefer 127.0.0.1 as it is perhaps a little more specific.

FYI: This is also true of localStorage...it will be different between 127.0.0.1 and localhost...which can lead to a whole mess thinking you app has issues that it doesn't actually have.